# How to apply a patch for a custom theme in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, patch

I am trying to replace the jQuery variables in the multiple JS files so I want to apply it as a patch.

I try to do it like this but the patch is not recognized.

```
     `"drupal/custom_theme":{ "Custom Theme Patch": "patches/new_patch.patch" }`
```

Comment: are you using lando? What errors are you getting?

Comment: The snippet you posted in your question look to be what would be added to your composer.json when using [cweagans/composer-patches](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches), unless your "custom theme" is required in your composer.json, it's not going to work.